# Derived class hiding base class same name method

Tags: c++, c++11

I was reading [this](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/005.htm) article and it states

> This calls Derived::f( complex ). Why? Well, remember that
> Derived doesn't declare "using Base:f;", and so clearly Base::f( int )
> and Base::f( double ) can't be called.

I decided to try this out and used this code

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void f( int ) {
        cout << "Base::f(int)" << endl;
    }

    virtual void f( double ) {
        cout << "Base::f(double)" << endl;
    }

    virtual void g( int i = 10 ) {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
};

class Derived: public Base {
    using Base::f;
    
public:
    void f( complex<double> ) {
        cout << "Derived::f(complex)" << endl;
    }

    void g( int i = 20 ) {
        cout << "Derived::g() " << i << endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    Derived d;

    d.f(1.0);        
}
```

I get the error
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':

```
main.cpp:43:16: error: 'virtual void Base::f(double)' is inaccessible within this context
   43 |         d.f(1.0);
```

My question is how do I use `using Base::f;` and how do I fix this issue ?

Comment: Maybe put `using Base::f;` under public section in `Derived` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. You should write the 'using' declaration under public section of class as below. If you put the declaration in private section, Base functions are available to Derived class but they will become private members of Derived class. That is why your compiler is throwing 'inaccessible' error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    virtual void f( int ) {
        cout << "Base::f(int)" << endl;
    }

    virtual void f( double ) {
        cout << "Base::f(double)" << endl;
    }

    virtual void g( int i = 10 ) {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
};

class Derived: public Base {
    
public:
    using Base::f;

    void f( complex<double> ) {
        cout << "Derived::f(complex)" << endl;
    }

    void g( int i = 20 ) {
        cout << "Derived::g() " << i << endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    Derived d;

    d.f(1.0);
}
```